# Recommendation for a dual valve mini pump with bottle cage bracket, gauge and thumb lock chuck (a hose nice to have)

Tags: product-rec

I currently use Lezyne Pressure Drive in medium size (21cm) with the body made of aluminium together with a replacement hose that comes with an inline gauge and is stored inside of the pump.

I find it perfect for my needs, not too small, not too big, with one major exception - the thread chuck has given me a lot of grief as far too often when I try to unscrew the chuck it also unscrews the Presta valve core. All this screwing and unscrewing is relatively time consuming and a very fiddly and frustrating task.

I'm looking for a similar product BUT **with a thumb lock rather than a screw-in chuck**. I guess I could compromise on the hose but I quite like a flexible connection like this rather than direct pump to a valve. A gauge is a must. The bracket is also required but if absent I guess I could either use what I have if the barrel of the replacement pump is of a similar size or find one that fits (or use Velcro, or maybe even have it 3D printed...).

[image]

Comment: VTC as shopping questions really don't work well.  But have you looked at the Topeak Road Morph? It's fiddly to change from Presta to Schrader but otherwise meets your specs.  You could probably even fit a replacement Road Morph head to your pump.  The related Mini Morph doesn't have the gauge, but the head for that might work with your nice inline gauge.  I doubt you'll get any kind of non-screw lock that fits inside the pump though

Comment: What's VTC? I did look at it and it was definitely too large for me. But I can now see that there is also Mini Morph G with a gauge that could be a potential candidate. The mount doesn't seem great but may be moddable. Great idea about trying to fit a different head, will give that a go. Wouldn't be able to keep it together with the pump but I can just store it in a saddle bag which is good enough.

Comment: VTC=vote to close - it's how we trim out questions we're not set up to deal with.  I've used a very similar Lezyne, and I think the diameter might be close enough to the Morphs that you could re-use the mount.  I've certainly reused an old mount like the one you picture with my mini morph.  Assuming you use a strap, gentle heat would allow you to reshape the mount for a different diameter.  I think the mountain morph might be fatter if the others are too thin

Comment: Pro tip: Use threadlocker on the valve core to prevent it coming loose. Or carry a valve core wrench with you. This one from Schwalbe is great (much better than the plastic ones one occasionally finds): https://r2-bike.com/SCHWALBE-valve-wrench-for-SV-and-AV-valves

Comment: @Michael I've modified my multitool to have mini pliers (penknife style).  They work well on valve cores and many other things.  Next time I buy a multitool I'll either get one with pliers built in, or get a tiny leatherman clone as well

Comment: Well, the only thing VTC achieved was that now the answers go into comments and people are not rewarded properly for their answers. Thanks for more tips! Yep, Lezyne is 21mm while Morph 28mm according to the spec, will try with 'expanding' the mount. Maybe I have to invest into a better multi-tool as having to carry another little bit doesn't sound that appealing. Also I got a puncture recently on a busy road and without being able to hear whether the core was about to pop out it was a painful experience, I'd rather use a better pump and not have to worry about it.

Comment: The main problem is just that valve cores are installed pretty loosely at the factory. Simply tighten them and/or use threadlocker. You just have to remember to do it for your spare tubes as well. I don’t like multi tools. I just have a valve core wrench, 4mm allen key, tyre levers and spare tube in my saddle bag. For what it’s worth: I also dislike the no product recommendations rule and don’t think it makes any sense.